# runtime exception when passing null as a parameter to a function

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am calling an Exception if the 'messageString' is not null passing the 'messageString' as an Argument as shown below

```
if (messageString !=null) {
  throw new org.jaffa.exceptions.ApplicationExceptions(
    new com.mirotechnologies.task.core.domain.exceptions.TaskException(
        com.mirotechnologies.task.core.domain.exceptions.TaskException.MANDATORY_FIELD, 
        messageString
    )
  );     
}
```

(I have to write the full path of classes since its inside AOP snippet)

It works fine if `messageString` is not `null` and displays the message appropriately.

But when it is `null`, it is actually throwing a run time error at the exception saying

```
undefined argument 'messageString' at : throw new org.jaffa.exceptions.ApplicationExceptions(new com.mirotechnologies.task.core.domain.exceptions.TaskException(com.mirotechnologies.task.core.domain.exceptions.TaskException.MANDATORY_FIELD, messageString));
```

Not able to debug this since its inside AOP, also not sure why does it go inside the loop if its null -  may be its a compiler issue of ambiguous null parameter to the TaskException constructor?

Here is the constructor declaration inside TaskException

```
public TaskException(String propertyName, Object parameter0) {
        this(propertyName, new Object[] {parameter0});
}

public TaskException(String propertyName, Object[] parameters) {
        super(propertyName, parameters);
}
```

Do I need to add a cast when passing the `messageString` in the java snippet

**Update**: I added a cast (Object )messageString when throwing the Exception and It throws the error now that **cannot cast 'void' value to java.lang.Object** - again why is it 'void', shouldnt it be not entering the loop since the messageString is null?

Initially the first line is declared as java.lang.String messageString = null;

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to guess that it is the ambiguity of `null` in the context of `TaskException's` constructors.

You might want to try calling:

```
new TaskException(TaskException.MANDATORY_FIELD, new Object[] {messageString})
```

Comment: Yes and thats right I have create the new object when passing the message in the Constructor. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey, it now  throws the exception "Void Array initialization at position 0", I think the best way out may be to set it to some value X which stands for empty throughout the code, and not actually use 'null' string value